# ReferenceError When Using dependOn in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Fairly new to webpack (sorry if this is kind of basic). From some searching, my understanding is that `import` declarations are unnecessary if you have the required packages in your `dependOn` in your webpack configuration. However, I get a `ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined` with the following config.

What am I doing wrong?

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        reactVendors: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        home: { import: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'), dependOn: 'reactVendors' }
    }
}
```

In my index.js

```
// removed import React from 'react' and import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' up here;

ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello</p>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing wrong is assuming that `dependOn` automatically makes `export`s available in the entry. `dependOn` adds the module code into the entry, but does not automatically wire up the `export`s/`import`s.

To fix the error, consider `import`ing the modules you'll use, rather than relying on `dependOn`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello</p>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```